# How dynamically update cache find_by_sql in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this query:

```
@constructions = Rails.cache.fetch(['city'], :expires_in => 24.hours){NewConstructions.all}
```

How I dynamically update the cache if user log in, or session is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute

```
Rails.cache.delete(['city'])
```

somewhere before that statement under the conditions you described. The cache will be empty then for that key and gets refilled.

Btw. I'm wondering why you are using `['city']` as the cache key. `'city'` has the same effect.